# Definition of a strictly increasing function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

What is the definition of strictly increasing for a function? Why does $f' >0$ imply $f$ is strictly increasing?

Much obliged if anyone can help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ defined on a set $X\subset \mathbb R$ is said to be *increasing* if $f(x)\leq f(y)$ whenever $x<y$ in $X$. If the inequality is strict, i.e., $f(x)<f(y)$ whenever $x<y$ in $X$, then $f$ is said to be *strictly increasing*.

A similar definition for *decreasing* and *strictly decreasing* applies (simply reverse all inequalities).

If $X$ is connected (so, an interval), then the result "$f'>0$ implies $f$ strictly increasing" is a consequence of the mean value theorem (essentially, if $x<y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$, then there must exist a point $z$ with $x\leq z\leq y$ with $f'(z)=0$ since the slope of the secant between $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$ would be $0$).

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot. But I feel sorry that I also want to know how to find what values of x is f strictly increasing , is it just to find what values of x is f' >0? Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Assuming $f'$ is continuous, we know that if $f'(x_0)>0$ then $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ in some open interval containing $x_0$ (by continuity). You can then find a maximal interval containing $x_0$ on which $f$ is strictly increasing: just put $$I_{x_0} = \bigcup\{J:x_0\in J, f'>0 {\textrm{ on }}J\}$$ There may be other intervals on which $f$ is strictly increasing as well. Note also that the condition $f'>0$ is not actually necessary (as with the function $x\mapsto x^3$).

Comment: @MPW: Sorry for the necropost: Don't we actually have $x>y$ iff $f(x)>f(y)$? (Equiv for decreasing)?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly increasing means if $x_1 < x_2$ then $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

One way to define the derivative is

$f'(x_2) = \lim_{x_1 \rightarrow x_2} \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} > 0$

From $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} > 0$ you can see, that if $x_2-x_1>0$ then so must be $f(x_2)-f(x_1)>0$ hence $f(x_2)>f(x_1)$.

Comment: $f'>0$ at $x_2$ does not imply $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$ for all $x_1$.

Comment: This argument is incorrect. The result is true, but not for the reason you suggest.

Comment: Please give an instructional example. I think this argument is valid if $x_2-x_1$ is small say $|x_2-x_1|<\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 0):

> A function $f(x)$ is said to be strictly increasing on an interval $I$
>   if $f(b)>f(a)$ for all $b>a,$ where $a,b$ in $I.$
>
> Conversely$,$ a function $f(x)$ decreases on an interval $I$ if
>   $f(b)<=f(a)$ for all $b>a$ with $a,b$ in $I.$ If $f(b)<f(a)$ for all
>   $b>a,$ the function is said to be strictly decreasing$.$
>
> On the other hand, if $f(b)>=f(a)$ for all $b>a,$ the function is
>   said to be (non-strictly) increasing.

Answer (score -1):

Let $A$ be the open subset where $f$ is differentiable. We know that $f'(x)>0$ for every $x \in A$. $f$ satisfies the criteria of the mean value theorem in $[x_1,x_2] \subset A$, therefore there exists $z \in (x_1, x_2)$ so that $f'(z)= \dfrac {f(x_1)-f(x_2)} {x_1-x_2}$. Since $f'(z)>0$, it follows that $\dfrac {f(x_1)-f(x_2)} {x_1-x_2}$, so $f(x_1)-f(x_2)>0$, i.e. $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$
(because $x_1<x_2$). Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing in $A$.